# Using the Sobol-Sequence to calculate pi in Julia

Tags: random, geometry, julia, pi

One can approximate pi by looking at the relationship of randomly generated points on a sqaure with a circle inside.

[image]

```
function picircle(n)
n = n
N = 2n+1

x = range(-1, 1, length=N)
y = rand(N)

center = (0,0)
radius = 1

n_in_circle = 0

for i in 1:N
    if norm((x[i], y[i]) .- center) < radius
        n_in_circle += 1
    end
end

println(4 * n_in_circle / N)
end
picircle(1000)
```

```
3.1424287856071964
```

However, I would like to use  the Quasi-Monte Carlo method. Instead of using pseudo random numbers I want to use numbers from a Sobol-Sequence. I know how to generate them but I am not sure how to implement it in my code.

```
using Sobol
s = SobolSeq(2) # Creates a Sobol-Sequenz in 2 Dimensions
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the [`README.md`](https://github.com/stevengj/Sobol.jl/blob/d52842736c9416cef1860f6238e86546fcac85c2/README.md#usage) of `Sobol.jl` to learn how to iterate over a `SobolSeq`.  The gist is that we can use `next!(s)` to get the next n elements, for an n-dimensional sequence.

```
julia> using Sobol

julia> s = SobolSeq(2)
2-dimensional Sobol sequence on [0,1]^2

julia> N = 10_000_000
10000000

julia> 4 * count(hypot(next!(s)...) < 1 for _ in 1:N) / N
3.1415952
```